# Why am I getting a compile error?

Tags: vba, excel

Let me preface my question by saying that I have no prior experience in any programming language. However, I am wanting to design a UserForm that allows users to enter information into specific areas in an Excel worksheet.

I am using 9 combo boxes and 1 text box. I verified that all of the combo boxes are correctly referenced in the code but I am continually getting a compile error when trying to make my "OK" button work.

```
Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub
Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
Dim RowCount As Long
Dim ctl As Control
RowCount = Worksheets("February Renewals").Range("S5").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
With Worksheets("February Renewals").Range("S5")
Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.ComboBoxStatus.Value
Offset(RowCount, 1).Value = Me.ComboBoxRemarketed.Value
Offset(RowCount, 2).Value = Me.ComboBoxCarrier1.Value
Offset(RowCount, 3).Value = Me.ComboBoxCarrier2.Value
Offset(RowCount, 4).Value = Me.ComboBoxCarrier3.Value
Offset(RowCount, 5).Value = Me.ComboBoxOptional1.Value
Offset(RowCount, 6).Value = Me.ComboBoxOptional2.Value
Offset(RowCount, 7).Value = Me.ComboBoxOptional3.Value
Offset(RowCount, 8).Value = Me.ComboBoxLost.Value
Offset(RowCount, 9).Value = Me.txtAdditionalNotes.Value
End Sub
```

Why am I getting this message and what can I do to resolve it?

Comment: What message are you getting?

Comment: Excel was just saying that it could not compile. Siddharth Rout answered my question below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a DOT before OFFSET. Try this

```
With Worksheets("February Renewals").Range("S5")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.ComboBoxStatus.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 1).Value = Me.ComboBoxRemarketed.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 2).Value = Me.ComboBoxCarrier1.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 3).Value = Me.ComboBoxCarrier2.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 4).Value = Me.ComboBoxCarrier3.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 5).Value = Me.ComboBoxOptional1.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 6).Value = Me.ComboBoxOptional2.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 7).Value = Me.ComboBoxOptional3.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 8).Value = Me.ComboBoxLost.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 9).Value = Me.txtAdditionalNotes.Value
End Sub
```